# some users cannot connect to DC occasionally

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

In my domain, I have two DCs running MS Server 2003.  One of them also has the role of the DHCP server. For some reason, few users are unable to connect to this DC from time to time. After a few days (3-14 days), they are able to connect to it. Right now, my laptop is one of the ones that cannot connect to it. I can ping and connect to other computers and servers, except this DC. This has been going on for several months. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define "connect".

Comment: Some of the shared folders located on the DC with the problem are inaccessible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any specific error messages? Is the issue happening at log in?

If you log in as a non domain user on the computer, can you ping the DC using it's domain name `\\server-name`? Its IP? If you run a wireshark on both computer and ping the DC, can you see if the DC is even receiving the pings? Is it responding but the client doesn't receive the response?

In my limited experience, problems connecting to the DC has usually been an issue with DNS. If you can ping the server by it's IP but not its domain name, try removing all DNS servers from the client's interface accept one of your DCs and see if that helps.

Comment: I used WireShark to monitor what happens when I ping both DCs.  The DC without problems replies to the request, while the DC with the problems does not reply to the request.  Thanks!

Comment: Were you running Wireshark from the affected DC or from your workstation?

Comment: I ran WireShark from my workstation.  I logged onto the affected DC and attempted to ping my computer, to no avail.  I see my computer in the 'Users and Computers'.  I deleted it, shut down my computer and restarted it after a while, to no avail.  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of connecting to our networking using a wired connection, I connected to our network wirelessly.  I was able to see shared drives on the affected DC and it worked without any problems.  I disconnected and tried to connect it using a wired connection, and ran into the same problem.  This leads me to think there might be a problem with my NIC.  Is there anything else I should try?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: However, on the other computer, I cannot access (or ping) a shared folder on the affected DC, either using a wired or wireless connection.  Please help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Execute **DCDIAG** and **NETDIAG**. Examine the log to find any errors. That would be a good start. Do you have WINS on your network?

Thanks.